# Find $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ given $\tan 2\theta$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Can you guys help with verifying my work for this problem. My answers don't match the given answers.

> Given $\tan 2\theta = -\dfrac{-24}{7}$, where $\theta$ is an acute angle, find $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$

I used the identity, $\tan 2\theta = \dfrac{2\tan \theta}{1 - tan^2 \theta}$ to try and get an equation in $\tan \theta$.

$$
\begin{align}
-\dfrac{24}{7} &= \dfrac{2\tan \theta}{1 - \tan^2 \theta} \\
-24 + 24\tan^2 \theta &= 14 \tan \theta \\
24tan^2 \theta - 14\tan \theta - 24 &= 0 \\
12tan^2 \theta - 7\tan \theta - 12 &= 0 \\
\end{align}
$$

Solving this quadratic I got,
$$ \tan \theta = \dfrac{3}{2} \text{ or } \tan \theta = -\dfrac{3}{4}$$

$$\therefore \sin \theta = \pm \dfrac{3}{\sqrt{13}} \text{ and } \cos \theta = \pm \dfrac{2}{\sqrt{13}}$$

Or,

$$\therefore \sin \theta = \pm \dfrac{3}{5} \text{ and } \cos \theta = \mp \dfrac{4}{5}$$

The given answer is,

> $$\sin \theta = \dfrac{4}{5} \text{ and } \cos \theta = \dfrac{3}{5}$$

I thought I needed to discard the negative solution assuming $\theta$ is acute. But they haven't indicated a quadrant. Do I assume the quadrant is I only? What am i missing? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: You didn't solve the quadratic for $\tan\theta$ correctly.

Comment: The condition given is $\theta$ is an acute angle.

Comment: If $\theta$ is an acute angle then you only want solutions where $\tan \theta$, $\sin \theta$, and $\cos \theta$ are all positive.

Comment: I guess it is to some extent a matter of convention, whether you call an angle in the range $(-\pi/2,0)$ acute or not. If you draw it, the angle sure looks acute. Whenever I give my students a problem like this, I specify the quadrant (unless I want them to find all the possible solutions). I don't know, if there is a standard for this in the English speaking regions of the world.

Comment: Thanks everyone, found the error. $\tan \theta = \dfrac{4}{3}$ and hence the given values of $\sin$ and $\cos$ follow. Also I am assuming that $\theta$ is acute in most similar problems implicitly implies Quadrant I, which explains why the given answers are only +ve.

Comment: @Gerry, Can you post your comment as an answer and make it community wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At Chandru's request:

1. The quadratic $12z^2-7z-12$ factors as $(3z-4)(4z+3)$ so we should get $\tan\,\theta=4/3$ and $\tan\,\theta=-3/4$.
2. "Acute angle" means "angle between 0 and $\pi/2$" means 1st quadrant.

Answer (score 0):

Given $ \tan(2\theta)= -\frac{24}{7}$ From the relation between $\sin(\theta)$, $\cos(\theta)$ and $\tan(\theta)$, we get $$ \frac{\sin(2\theta)}{\cos(2\theta)}= -\frac{24}{7} \implies \sin(2\theta)= -\frac{24}{7} \cos(2\theta)$$and $$ \sin(2\theta)^2 + \cos(2\theta)^2=1$$ $$\cos(2\theta) = \pm \frac{7}{25} \implies 2 \cos^2(\theta)-1 = \pm \frac{7}{25}$$ Case 1: Rational number on the right is positive, $$\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{16}{25} \implies \cos(\theta) = \pm \frac{4}{5} $$ Solution to case 1:
 $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{4}{5}$$$$  \sin(\theta)=\frac{3}{5}.$$ Both sine and cosine functions are positive, for $\theta$ being acute. 
 Case 2:Rational number on the right is negative $$\cos^2(\theta)=\frac{9}{25} \implies \cos(\theta) = \pm \frac{3}{5} $$Solution to case 2:
 $$\cos(\theta)=\frac{3}{5} $$$$  \sin(\theta)=\frac{4}{5}.$$ Both sine and cosine functions are positive, for $\theta$ being acute.